# Java double checked locking - Strings

Tags: java, multithreading, double-checked-locking

Given that `string`s contain final field, does it mean in the context of double checked locking it is not necessary to declare them `volatile`? E.g.

```
class SomeClass{
     private String val;

     String getVal(){
           if(val == null){
                synchronized(this){
                      if(val ==null)
                           val = new String("foo");
                }
          }
     }
}
```

I used a string as an example, but it should work with other objects that declare some final field, correct?

Comment: Since `"foo"` is already in your constant string pool, there is absolutely no advantage to not initializing the field straight away and making it final, doing away with all of this extra syntax and unnecessary object creation.

Comment: What fields `String` has is largely irrelevant, the important thing is that it is immutable. But this `synchronization` pattern is both defective and unnecessary.

Comment: Forgetting about Strings - if that type was Foo, and Foo had a final field, would volatile be necessary?

Comment: @Bober02 Having a final field isn't enough, all the fields must be final and the object thus completely immutable. And in those cases volatile is indeed not required.

Comment: @biziclop - Cheers, sounds good!

Answer (score 2):

For strings you're right. A string which is declared final cannot be differed and therefore you do not need to synchronize when using it.

Thats not true for other Objects. Take this little class for example:

```
public class BankAccount {
    private int balance = 0;
    public void addMoney(int money) {
        balance+=money;
    }
}
```

When you've got a final Object of this class it doesn't mean that nobody can change the fields inside the object. You just can't assign something else to the final variable!

Conclusion: When accessing final String you don't need to synchronize, when accessing final Objects you might have to, depending on the Object itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, you still have to declare `val` as volatile here.  The problem is that while `String` is immutable and thread safe, `val` is not.  You still have a visibility problem with `val` itself.

To address your point about "given that String contains a final field," note that the JLS specifically says that visibility is not transitive when dealing with `final` fields.

> Given a write w, a freeze f, an action a (that is not a read of a final field), a read r1 of the final field frozen by f, and a read r2 such that hb(w, f), hb(f, a), mc(a, r1), and dereferences(r1, r2), then when determining which values can be seen by r2, we consider hb(w, r2). (This happens-before ordering does not transitively close with other happens-before orderings.)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Where a "freeze f" is how the JLS refers to the thread-safe part of `final` field semantics, i.e., the part that actually makes the object referenced by the field visible.

(There are cases where you *can* rely on transitivity with *synchronizes-with* and *happens-before.*  Brian Goetz calls this 'piggy-backing' and talks about it in *Java Concurrency in Practice.*  But it's pretty much experts only and I don't recommend it until you are an expert with the Java memory model.)

In short, declare `val` volatile and don't worry about saving two nanoseconds by skipping synchronization.  The extra rigmarole in the code isn't worth it, and it doesn't work anyway.